# Catch push notification text on lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

How can I get the push notification text when the app does not run or in lock screen?

I did try:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    println(userInfo)
    // or just
    println("something")
}
```

But it doesn't print me anything. Is it wrong function???

Answer (score 1):

**didReceiveRemoteNotification** function only called this condition.

1. while app will running and app in foreground.(alert not showing)
2. if app in background and click notification on home screen

if app not run in device **didReceiveRemoteNotification** function not called, 
in this case user click notification in home screen, we identify app launched by notification or not in  **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif =[launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

you get userinfo data in `localNotif.userinfo`

Try in Swift

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
 var userinfo : NSDictionary =launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        print(launchOptions);
        return true
    }
```

Comment: can you write it in Swift, please? And, how can do what I described in my question? Can you help me with it?

Comment: @Orkhan Alizade pls check my above code, i am new for swift  so if any changes in swift code pls correct